# Как сделать, чтобы у объектов grid сохранялся display: inline-block?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, css-grid

Недавно начал делать надписи у слайдшоу, и пришел к тому, что при большой ширине экрана заголовок и текст сливаются в один ряд (при маленькой ширине все нормально). Но когда я попытался исправить проблему с помощью grid, то bgcolor распространился на всю сетку. Как это исправить ?

P.S. Также пробовал ограничивать ширину текстового блока, но тогда при уменьшении ширины терялся нужный вид.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.ss-item-text {
  /* display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr;*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 5%;
  /*width: 60%;*/
}

.h1-ss-item {
  background: var(--dark-blue);
  color: var(--green);
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.p-ss-item {
  width: 80%;
  background: var(--dark-blue);
  color: var(--green);
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.ss-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60vh;
  margin-right: 0;
  background: #8C8;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="ss-item">
  <div class="ss-item-text">
    <h1 class="h1-ss-item">Комфорт</h1>
    <p class="p-ss-item">
      Велсофт создан для домашнего комфорта и уюта. Её пушистый, мягкий ворс напоминает велюр, но отличается особой шелковистостью и нежностью. Изделия из этого материала дарят и взрослым, и детям ощущения особого домашнего тепла и покоя
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.ss-item-text {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr;
 position: absolute;
 top: 60%;
 left: 5%;
 /*width: 60%;*/
}
```

[image: P.S.]

```css
.ss-item-text {
 /*display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr;*/
 position: absolute;
 top: 60%;
 left: 5%;
 width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: А чем float не угодил?

Comment: @Qwertie В каком плане ?

Comment: Ну я бы float использовал просто. А может и нет...

Comment: @Qwertie Нет, они также в одну строку, только теперь стоят ближе друг к другу

Comment: Добавь нижнему `clear: left` и он перенесётся.

Comment: @Qwertie Тебе мама говорила, что ты гений ?

Answer (score 1):

```
.h1-ss-item {
    background: var(--dark-blue);
    color: var(--green);
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.p-ss-item {
    width: 80%;
    background: var(--dark-blue);
    color: var(--green);
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```